# Tensorflow: lable_image "failed to download and install inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb.tar.gz"

Tags: tensorflow

while running this code

```
curl -L "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb.tar.gz" |
  tar -C tensorflow/examples/label_image/data -xz"
```

I got following error:

```
**% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locat
ions:
  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now**
```

Any idea what is wrong with it?

Kind Regards,
Mansoor

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what leads to this error message (since this looks like some certificate error), but I think the target directory must exist before executing the tar command. The following chain of commands should fit your needs:

```
curl -L -o test.tar.gz "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb.tar.gz" && mkdir -p tensorflow/examples/label_image/data && tar xvzf test.tar.gz -C tensorflow/examples/label_image/data && rm test.tar.gz
```

Comment: thanks dear. it was certificate error in the end. Fixed it. Thanks for the help.